# Unable to connect to S3 while creating Elasticsearch snapshot repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, amazon-eks

I am trying to register a respository on AWS S3 to store ElasticSearch snapshots.
I am following [guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/repository-s3.html) and ran the very first command listed in the doc.
But I am getting the error Access Denied while executing that command.
[image]
The role that is being used to perform operations on S3 is the **AmazonEKSNodeRole**.
I have assigned the appropriate permissions to the role to perform operations on the S3 bucket.
Also, here is another [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-aws-custom-repository.html#ec-create-aws-repository) which suggests to use kibana for ElasticSearch version > 7.2 but I am doing the same via cURL requests.
Below is trust Policy of the role through which I am making the request to register repository in the S3 bucket.
[image]
Also, below are the screenshots of the permissions of the trusting and trusted accounts respectively -
[image]
[image]

Comment: FOllow https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/managedomains-snapshots.html.

Comment: @Riz, but I am not using Amazon Opensearch service. I have deployed a ElasticSearch as an external load-balancer service on K8s. Should I still follow the documentation you provided

Comment: ah my bad. Your issue is with the role you are using. You need `es.amazonaws.com` in the `principal` in the trust relationship.

Comment: @Riz, I have added the above service principal in the trust policy of the role, but still I am getting the same error. I have added the screenshots of the trust policy of the role and the permissions of the trusting and trusted accounts in the question.